# iccube : in a google column chart, how to define gap between columns?

Tags: google-visualization, iccube-reporting

In iccube reporting V6, we can define columns width for google column charts, is there a way to define the gap between columns instead ?

Comment: not listed in the typical config options for each chart type, you can find possible options in the release notes -- see notes for release on [February, 23 2016](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes#february-23-2016) -- options were added for --> `bar.width`, `bar.gap`, `bar.group.width` (was `bar.groupWidth`) and `bar.group.gap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no possibility to define width of gaps before **IcCube 6.1 (4194)**, but as you already mentioned it is possible to define columns' width. With defined chart's width we can achieve needed gap between columns.

### After 6.1 (4194)

**Bar Gap** and **Bar Width** options were added under **Advanced Configuration > Appearance**:

Bar Gap option exactly serves your needs, but I'd like to notice that if it's defined chart ignores "Bar Width" and "Bar Group Width" properties.